# Use of unresolved identifier 'kUTTypePDF'

Tags: swift

How to use the file types in Swift

according to 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kuttypepdf

this should be completely fine

```
UIPasteboard.general.setData(Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)), forPasteboardType: kUTTypePDF)
```

yet it yelds

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'kUTTypePDF'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to import `import MobileCoreServices` as "Robert Dresler" said

But you will see below error after `import MobileCoreServices`

> 'CFString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

So you need to do `kUTTypePDF as String`

After that you may see an error in `Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)` as like below,

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

So you need to use `try` and `catch`.

You final code will looks like below.

```
do{

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

        UIPasteboard.general.setData(data, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePDF as String)

    }catch{

        print("error :\(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to import `MobileCoreServices`

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Comment: Note: in Xcode 11.4 `MobileCoreServices` was renamed to `CoreServices`.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

That will make the problem go away.

Swift 4:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```